# Exception Coming when i integrate payu payment getway with android app

Tags: android

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        String merchant_key = "JBZaLc";
        String salt = "GQs7yium";
        String action1 = "";
        String base_url = "https://test.payu.in";
        String txnid = "TXN8367286482920";
        String amount = "1000";
        String productInfo = "This good Product";
        String firstName = "Rajesh";
        String emailId = "rajeshmcashc10@gmail.com";
        private String SUCCESS_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/contactus.html";
        private String FAILED_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/contactus.html";
        private String phone = "9999389917";
        private String serviceProvider = "payu_paisa";
        private String hash = "";
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        WebView webView;
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            JSONObject productInfoObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray productPartsArr = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject productPartsObj1 = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject paymentIdenfierParent = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray paymentIdentifiersArr = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject paymentPartsObj1 = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject paymentPartsObj2 = new JSONObject();
            try {
                // Payment Parts
                productPartsObj1.put("name", "abc");
                productPartsObj1.put("description", "abcd");
                productPartsObj1.put("value", "1000");
                productPartsObj1.put("isRequired", "true");
                productPartsObj1.put("settlementEvent", "EmailConfirmation");
                productPartsArr.put(productPartsObj1);
                productInfoObj.put("paymentParts", productPartsArr);
                // Payment Identifiers
                paymentPartsObj1.put("field", "CompletionDate");
                paymentPartsObj1.put("value", "31/10/2012");
                paymentIdentifiersArr.put(paymentPartsObj1);
                paymentPartsObj2.put("field", "TxnId");
                paymentPartsObj2.put("value", txnid);
                paymentIdentifiersArr.put(paymentPartsObj2);
                paymentIdenfierParent.put("paymentIdentifiers",
                        paymentIdentifiersArr);
                productInfoObj.put("", paymentIdenfierParent);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            productInfo = productInfoObj.toString();

            Log.e("TAG", productInfoObj.toString());

            Random rand = new Random();
            String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            txnid = hashCal("SHA-256", rndm).substring(0, 20);

            hash = hashCal("SHA-512", merchant_key + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount
                    + "|" + productInfo + "|" + firstName + "|" + emailId
                    + "|||||||||||" + salt);

            action1 = base_url.concat("/_payment");

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                            String description, String failingUrl) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                               SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SslError! " + error,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Page Started! " + url,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (url.equals(SUCCESS_URL)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success! " + url,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure! " + url,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
                //
                // @Override
                // public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                //
                // Toast.makeText(PayMentGateWay.this, "" + url,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // }
            });

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(MainActivity.this),
                    "PayUMoney");
            Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mapParams.put("key", merchant_key);
            mapParams.put("hash", hash);
            mapParams.put("txnid", txnid);
            mapParams.put("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
            mapParams.put("amount", amount);
            mapParams.put("firstname", firstName);
            mapParams.put("email", emailId);
            mapParams.put("phone", phone);
            mapParams.put("productinfo", productInfo);
            mapParams.put("surl", SUCCESS_URL);
            mapParams.put("furl", FAILED_URL);
            mapParams.put("lastname", "Vijayakumar");
            mapParams.put("address1", "sdas");
            mapParams.put("address2", "dasd");
            mapParams.put("city", "adsa");
            mapParams.put("state", "asdas");
            mapParams.put("country", "adsas");
            mapParams.put("zipcode", "45465");
            mapParams.put("udf1", "sdaa");
            mapParams.put("udf2", "adsasd");
            mapParams.put("udf3", "adsad");
            mapParams.put("udf4", "adsd");
            mapParams.put("udf5", "dasdas");
            // mapParams.put("pg", (empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"))) ?
            // ""
            // : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"));
            webview_ClientPost(webView, action1, mapParams.entrySet());

        }

        public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
            Context mContext;

            /**
             * Instantiate the interface and set the context
             */
            PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        mHandler = null;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public void webview_ClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                                       Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("<html><head></head>");
            sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
            sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>",
                    url, "post"));
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
                sb.append(String.format(
                        "<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />",
                        item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
            }
            sb.append("</form></body></html>");
            Log.d("Tag", "webview_ClientPost called");
        //    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
            webView.postUrl("https://secure.payu.in/_payment", EncodingUtils.getBytes(sb.toString(), "base64"));

        }

        public boolean empty(String s) {
            if (s == null || s.trim().equals(""))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
            byte[] hashseq = str.getBytes();
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
                algorithm.reset();
                algorithm.update(hashseq);
                byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

                for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                    if (hex.length() == 1)
                        hexString.append("0");
                       hexString.append(hex);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            }
            return hexString.toString();

        }
}
```

this is my code which i have applied in payu payment getaway integration with android app but when i run this app in test Mode then there is exception coming

Exception is below:

```
primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=*.payubiz.in,O=Payu Payments pvt. ltd.,L=Gurgaon,ST=Haryana,C=IN;
Issued by: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US;
```

and this exception coming at line onReceivedSslError method please suggest me where am doing wrong please help : 
[image]
screen is coming like this after run app :

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following merchant and salt keys for testing in payyou

```
 private String mMerchantKey = "gtKFFx";
    private String mSalt = "eCwWELxi";
```

Comment: Still same Exception coming after change key and Mkey @Lakhan

Comment: just try to log your all details